# How can I put some paragraphs on each other in LaTeX? As in the picture below

Tags: overleaf, latex3

I want to put some sentences on each other.
[image: picture]

Comment: Welcome. // What‘s the purpose? Corrections?

Comment: No. It's not corrections. It's a design on a cover. I just want to put some sentences like a stack.

Comment: For graphic design it may be better to use an actual (vector) graphics editor, like InDesign or Inkscape or LibreOffice Draw. This is much more flexible (and WYSIWYG) than trying to make LaTeX do something weird (although it is definitely possible). If you need actual LaTeX output (like math) then you could maybe copy and paste from the pdf into your graphics editor.

Comment: I know Latex is not suitable for graphic design. But I have to do it using Latex. Just tell me how to do it.

Comment: Not to be rude, but this is not a **please do this for me** service! If the write edge around the red text is square, you can do this using tikz in latex by just stacking appropriate nodes.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I didn't mean this.

Comment: Look for tikz, which was already mentioned. Also look for \raisebox{}. For colour see topic color at ctan: https://www.ctan.org/topic/colour (you probably want xcolor). Use this sites search field, for example. // This tends to be a friendly place, so be kind too, please.

Answer (score 3):

I know that you are asking for LaTeX. But you didn't give any starting LaTeX code in your question an I don't like LaTeX. So I show you the code which can be processed directly by OpTeX, no LaTeX. But main idea is here clearly shown and it is based only on TeX primitives: `\baselineskip`, `\par`, `\vbox`, `\setbox`, `\hsize`, `\kern` and `\def`. They can be used in the same way in your LaTeX. You can inspire by this code and re-write it to LaTeX.

```
\def\shadowpar#1{\par
   \bgroup
   \baselineskip=20pt 
   \setbox0=\vbox{\hsize=15cm #1}
   \setbox1=\vbox{\hsize=16cm \Red #1}
   \vbox to0pt{\box0\vss}\kern5pt \box1
   \egroup
}


\shadowpar{%
   When a battery is supplying power, its positive terminal is the cathode
   and its negative terminal is the anode. 
   When a battery is supplying power, its positive terminal is the cathode
   and its negative terminal is the anode. 
   When a battery is supplying power, its positive terminal is the cathode
   and its negative terminal is the anode. 
   When a battery is supplying power, its positive terminal is the cathode
   and its negative terminal is the anode. 
}

\bye
```

Comment: About rewriting: this works almost unchanged in LaTeX. Just add a documentclass, `\usepackage{xcolor}`, begin/end document, remove `\bye`. The only code change is to use `\color{red}` instead of `\Red`. The resulting paragraph is shifted a bit into the right margin though, I'm not sure why that happens.